# how to manage multiple notifications from same application

Tags: android, notifications, alarmmanager

I am new to android. I am working on application which fire notifications. When I have more than one notifications on status bar and I click on second, The first one will be opened. I am able to get Id of only first notification. How to select particular notification Id I click. Here is my code

```
 save.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

     for(int i=1;i<gpPeople.size();i++)
     {
         Context ctx = SetReminder.this.getApplicationContext();
         Intent intent = new Intent(SetReminder.this, AlarmReciever.class);
         intent.putExtra("contactName",gpPeople.get(i));
         intent.putExtra("id", id);//unique notification Id
         PendingIntent objPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(SetReminder.this, i, intent, 0);
         AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)ctx.getSystemService(ctx.ALARM_SERVICE);
         alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, StartTime, cal.getTimeInMillis(), objPendingIntent);
     }
 }
```

AlarmReciever.java

```
 public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent) {

 name= extras.getString("contactName");
 String id= extras.getString("id");
 notificationIdentifier= Integer.parseInt(id);

 Intent intent1 = new Intent(context, Notifications.class);
 PendingIntent objPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent1, 0);

 Intent intent2= new Intent(context, CancelNotification.class);
 intent2.putExtra("id", notificationIdentifier);
 PendingIntent objPendingCancel = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent2, 0);

 Intent intent3= new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL,Uri.parse("tel:"+phones.get(0).trim())); 
 PendingIntent objPendingCall = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent3, 0);

 Intent intent4= new Intent(context, Snooze.class);
 intent4.putExtra("id", notificationIdentifier);
 intent4.putExtra("name", name);
 PendingIntent objPendingSnooze = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent4, 0);

 notification = new Notification.Builder(context).
                setContentTitle(notificationTitle).
                setContentText(notificationMessage+" "+name).
                setAutoCancel(true).setSmallIcon(icon).
                setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis()).
                addAction(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_call,"call",objPendingCall).
                addAction(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_delete, "Cancel", objPendingCancel).
                addAction(android.R.drawable.ic_lock_idle_alarm,"Snooze",objPendingSnooze).
                setContentIntent(objPendingIntent).
                build();
            notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;
            notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
            notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS;
            final NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            notificationManager.notify(notificationIdentifier, notification);
 }
```

When I click on call button of any one of notifications only first one will be operated. Please help me to get Id of particular notification. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Your "notificationIdentifier" should be unique for every notification.

You can put the notification code in a method:

```
    public void notification (int notificationIdentifier){
notification = new Notification.Builder(context).
                setContentTitle(notificationTitle).
                setContentText(notificationMessage+" "+name).
                setAutoCancel(true).setSmallIcon(icon).
                setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis()).
                addAction(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_call,"call",objPendingCall).
                addAction(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_delete, "Cancel", objPendingCancel).
                addAction(android.R.drawable.ic_lock_idle_alarm,"Snooze",objPendingSnooze).
                setContentIntent(objPendingIntent).
                build();
            notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;
            notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
            notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS;
            final NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            notificationManager.notify(notificationIdentifier, notification);  
    };
```

and call the method where you want it with:

```
notification (notificationIdentifier);
```

If there is no meaning to the id you can use a random number:

```
Random rand = new Random();
notificationIdentifier = rand.nextInt(1000000) + 1;
```